# Get the parent term with child term

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I get the parent and child term of a custom post type. I have code below that partly works, the problem is it does not generate child and parent term in same div but different div as loop. Due to lack of knowledge on PHP, I am not really sure how to fix it.

What I want if I have parent and child as;

```
 - USA
  - New York
```

The out come should be;

```
USA, New York
```

but with below code it generates as

```
,USA
,New York
```

Code;

```
<div class="address">
<?php

$terms = get_terms(array(
   'taxonomy' => 'people-country',
   'hide_empty' => false,
 ));
?>
<?php foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>
<?php
     $re = explode('-', $term->name);
     $args = array (
         'post_type' => 'people', //
         'posts_per_page' => 2,
         'order' => 'ASC',
         'tax_query'     => array(
              array(
                 'taxonomy'  => 'people-country',
                 'field'     => 'id',
                 'terms'     => $term->term_id,
              ),
          ),
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $query->have_posts() ){
         while( $query->have_posts() ){
             $query->the_post();
             $title =  get_the_title();
             // $info = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_post_info', true);
             // $link = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'link', true);
    ?>

        <div class="text">
                <span class="number"><?php echo ",".$re[0] ?>
            </span>

        </div>

    <?php
        }
    }
endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: I hope this will help you
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_get_term_hierarchy

Comment: Thank you @MadhuriPatel, I just solved it

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it by changing it with below code;

```
<?php
$cats = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'people-country');
$names = array();

if ($cats) foreach ($cats as $cat) {
  if ($cat->parent) {
      array_push($names, $cat->name);
  }
}

if ($cats) foreach ($cats as $cat) {
  if (!$cat->parent) {
      array_push($names, $cat->name);
  }
}
?>
<?php echo implode(', ', $names) ?>
```